# How to find the residue of an even function at a pole of order $~n~?$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> **Question:** How to find the residue of an even function at a pole of order $~n~?$

I know how to find the residue of a function depending on the nature of the singularity. But the above question stuck me. I am unable to figure out the solution of this particular question.

**What I done till now:** Mathematically if I describe this question I got,

> Let $~f(z)~$ be an even function and has a pole of order $~n~$ at $~z=z_0~$. Then what is the value of $~\text{Res}\left(f,z_0\right)~?$

Now let $~f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}~,$ where $~g(z)~$ be an analytic funtion, then

$$~\text{Res}\left(f,z_0\right)~=\frac 1{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left[(z-z_0)^nf(z)\right]=\frac 1{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left[g(z)\right]~.$$

Then what ?

Where I have to use the property of an ***even function*** ?

Any one please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "even" in this context? If it's the usual "$f(-z) = f(z)$", then do you also mean to take $z_0=0$?

Comment: $(z)=f(-z)\Rightarrow a_{2n-1}=0$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}$

Comment: @MPW: even function means $~f(z)=f (-z)~.$ But I am unable to understand why we take $~z_0=0~?$

Comment: @Gio:  I am unable to get your indication. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: If $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}(z-c)^{n}$ for some $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ then for any   $(b_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ such that  $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_{n}(z-c)^{n}$ one can infer that $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, by Laurent Theorem. Let $b_{n}=(-1)^{n}a_{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $z_0 = 0$ then the residue must be zero: In the Laurent series
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_k z^k
$$
of $f$ at $z=0$ all odd-indexed coefficients are zero because $f$ is even. It follows that
$$
 \operatorname{Res}(f, 0) = a_{-1} = 0 \, .
$$

If $z_0 \ne 0$ then nothing can be said about the residue: For arbitrary complex numbers $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ with $c_n \ne 0$ the function
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{c_k}{(z-z_0)^k} + \frac{c_k}{(-z-z_0)^k} \right)
$$
is even and has a pole of order $n$ at $z_0$ with $\operatorname{Res}(f, z_0) = c_1$.